# How can you change the file being redirected to while script is still running?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Assume I have this script running continually:

node myprogram.js > logfile.log

If I want to make the output dump to a new log file every day without stopping or restarting "node myprogram.js", what should I do?

For example, every day, I want to see the logs saved as 2015-12-01.log, 2015-12-02.log, 2015-12-03.log, etc, and not have the logs be dumped into a single file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use logrotate  its the pre-installed utility most linux OS's use for what you are talking about plus more, typical default settings would involve automatically compressing log files of a certain age and then eventually deleting the oldest log files.
The utility runs automatically once a day and performs log rotations as per a configuration you define.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer this question in server fault sister site. Nonetheless, there are many tools to use. Check out logrotate / rotatelogs.